# Show that the last component of an eigenvector of a tridiagonal hermitian matrix is not 0.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A= (a_{ij})$ be hermitian and tridiagonal such that $a_{i\space  i+1} \neq 0$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n-1$ Let $B$ be the matrix obtained from deleting the last row and last column of $A$. Let $x = (x_1 , \dots x_n)^T$ be an eigenvector for $A$. Show that $x_n \neq 0$

We know that $A$ has the following form:

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
B & y \\
y^* & a \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $y \in \mathbb{C}^{n-1}$ and $a \in \mathbb{C}$. Now assume that $x_n=0$ and let $v=(x_1 \dots x_{n-1} , 0)^T$ so then :

$$\begin{bmatrix}
B & y \\
y^* & a\\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
v \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix} = \lambda 
\begin{bmatrix}
v \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
Bv \\
y^*v \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda v \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Therefore $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $B$ with eigenvector $v$ and $y^*v=0$. From here I am unsure how to proceed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since $y$ has all entries zero except the last one $y_{n-1}$, which is non-zero, $y*v = 0$ implies that $v_{n - 1} = 0$. Thus, $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$ (which is also Hermitian, tridiagonal, and with all super- and sub-diagonals non-zero, just like $A$), with its last component $v_{n - 1}$ zero. Recursively (or by induction), we see that $x = 0$.

Comment: Of course! that makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be a Hermitian tridiagonal matrix of order $n$, with $a_{i, i + 1} \ne 0$, $i = 1, \ldots, n - 1$.

Write $A = \begin{bmatrix} A^{(1)} & y\\y^* & a\end{bmatrix}$, as you have defined, and suppose that $x = \begin{bmatrix}x^{(1)} \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector. Then
$$Ax = \lambda x \implies \begin{bmatrix} A^{(1)} & y\\y^* & a\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x^{(1)} \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \lambda \begin{bmatrix}x^{(1)} \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \implies \begin{array}{l} A^{(1)} x^{(1)} = \lambda x^{(1)}\\ y^*x^{(1)} = 0\end{array}.$$

Since $A$ is tridiagonal with $a_{n,n+1} \ne 0$, $y^* = \begin{bmatrix}0 & \cdots & 0 & a^*_{n,n+1}\end{bmatrix}$, so that $y^*x^{(1)} = 0 \implies x^{(1)}_{n-1} = 0$.

Now, $A^{(1)}$ is a Hermitian tridigonal matrix of order $n - 1$, with $a^{(1)}_{i, i+1} \ne 0$, $i = 1, \ldots, n - 2$, and having $x^{(1)} = \begin{bmatrix}x^{(2)} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ as an eigenvector. Thus, by induction, we find that every component of $x$ is zero, which contradicts the assumption that $x$ is an eigenvector.

Thus, any eigenvector of $A$ must have a non-zer0 $n$<sup>th</sup> component.